# Facebook authentication and GraphAPI calls in asp.net core 1.1

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to create a basic solution to authenticate with Facebook on a Web Site created with Asp.net Core 1.1 and Core Identity, Visual Studio 2017.

I followed the official documentation and it works as described, but that is not the scenario that lots of people would like.  After login with Facebook a second screen is shown asking to register an email (why is this if Facebook already has your email?).  So i don´t want to present this second screen, but to access the email already stored in Facebook, and after that be able to use the Facebook Graph API in different controllers of my application.  After hours of research i was able to remove that second screen and complete the authentication flow, but also found that for Asp.net Core Microsoft doesn't have a Package to access the API( It is available for Asp.Net MVC, but not for Core), so i will need to access the API by using HttpClient and call the Rest API directly, but for doing that i will need to have inside my controllers the Access Token that Facebook issued.

How can i access, inside my controllers, the "Access Token" of the user currently authorized?  I need to call the API inside my controllers.  Please help.